Play ads at specific times of a video in ExoPlayer
In Android (kotlin) am using ExoPlayer 2.18.1 to stream movies, and in order to add ads to these movies i used IMA extension adsLoader to load ads and play them, currently I am using only a test adTagUrl, and the ads are playing before the video starts playing (preroll).
Is there a way to play ads at specific times of the video?
for example I want to play the ad after 60 seconds of the video start
Another thing that i cant achieve is to play ads multiple times,
I have some long videos, and I want to play multiple ads on them
I have looked for ways to manually load and start ads but i could not found any.
This is my current code to stream movies and inject ads to them:
val trackSelectorParameters = DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder(this).build()
        val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(this)
        trackSelector.parameters = trackSelectorParameters
        videoUrl = playerData.url
        val videoUri = Uri.parse(videoUrl)
        val adTagUri = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.ad_tag_url))

        mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
            .setUri(videoUri)
            .setAdsConfiguration(AdsConfiguration.Builder(adTagUri).build())
            .build()

        player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
            .build()
        adsLoader!!.setPlayer(player)

        activityPlayerBinding.playerView.player = player
        player!!.trackSelectionParameters = player!!.trackSelectionParameters
            .buildUpon()
            .setMaxVideoSizeSd()
            .setPreferredAudioLanguage("hu")
            .build();
        player!!.addListener(PlayerEventListener(this))
        activityPlayerBinding.playerView.setControllerVisibilityListener {
            if(it == 0) activityPlayerBinding.playerOptions.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            else activityPlayerBinding.playerOptions.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        mediaSource = DefaultMediaSourceFactory(this)
            .setAdsLoaderProvider { adsLoader }
            .setAdViewProvider(playerView)
            .createMediaSource(mediaItem)
        player?.let {
            it.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
            it.seekTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(viewModel.playerVideoData.value!!.duration.toLong()))
            it.prepare()
            it.play()
        }

